# I want to find the trip detail(Trip start point, End Trip point, Speed, Hard Breaking, Phone usage, Accident) of user. (Android Development)

Tags: android, gps

How are Driving Events tracked?

I need these information in android. Is there any SDK or lib for this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can be a good start point for you https://developers.google.com/location-context/activity-recognition

Comment: what do you mean by phone usage ? phone usage while driving ?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use activity `recognition api` to detect motion this will
    give you start and end point
2) speed you can get by  speed
    =`location.getSpeed()`; or you can store lat , lng with time stamp so you can calculate distance between two lat lng divide by elapsed
    time that will give you speed.

3) based on acceleration you can calculate harsh acceleration or
    harsh breaking using linear acceleration value compared with last
    acceleration value can be calculated by

```
     SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

for calculating harsh acceleration and breaking you will have to calculate G-force value from acceleration.

**Note : You have to make this calculations in service ( foreground service if you want location to be tracked in background**

Comment: akshay_shahane I have already done this using activity_Recognition API and accelerometer but when my service calculate all these things it take time and also effect battery optimization, I want any SDK or lib to these things in one, I have read about SDK sucj like that (RideMetric) and (Sentiance) SDK but they don't give the app_secret key i don't know why, i have contact with them but didn't get any reply from them.

Comment: what my opinion is no matter which sdk or lib you use it will drain your battery as you are dealing with GPS . even google maps drains battery a lot,